# How to check the given number is positive or negative in i386 assembly language

Tags: assembly, x86

Following code doesn't work

`cmp ax, 0
jl NegativeNumber ;jump to negative statements`

```
test ax , 0x80 ;to compare sign bit. but it doesn't work
```

Assembler doesn't jump to the NegativeNumber procedure, although the entered number is negative.

Following is my actual code

```
section .data 
str1:db 10,13, 'Enter the number'
str1len equ 19
str2: db 10,13, 'The number is positive'
str2len equ 22
str3 : db 10, 13, 'The number is negative'
str3len equ 22

section .bss

    num resw 1
    cbuff resw 1


global _start
section .text
_start:

%macro sys_read 2
    mov rax,0
    mov rdi,0
    mov rsi,%1
    mov rdx,%2
    syscall
%endmacro

%macro sys_write 2
    mov rax,1
    mov rdi,1
    mov rsi,%1
    mov rdx,%2
    syscall

%endmacro

    call GetNumber



GetNumber:
     sys_write str1, str1len
     sys_read cbuff , 1
     mov ax , [cbuff]
     cmp ax , 0h
     jl NumberNegative
         sys_write str2, str2len 
         ret

NumberNegative:

    sys_write str3, str3len
        ret
```

Is there any other way to identify given number is positive or negative without using flags?
Is am i doing something wrong?
BTW i am using NASM on Linux ubuntu.

Comment: What's `as`? Did you mean `ax`? Also, if you're dealing with 16-bit numbers you should be checking bit 15, not bit 7 (or just do `test ax,ax`, `js Negative`).

Comment: Yes. Sorry. Its ax. I corrected question now. Ok, Can you please tell me how can i check the 15 bit? Thanks

Comment: 2^15 = 0x8000, use that.

Comment: @MargaretBloom can you please tell me a more code about that. That will be a great help.

Comment: I am waiting for your reply!!!

Comment: @Shreyas [see this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41706135/how-to-solve-assembler-expression#comment70608265_41706135)

Comment: `cmp ax,0` `jl NegativeNumber` is correct, so your error is elsewhere. There's shorter way `test ax,ax` to replace `cmp ax,0` in this particular case (detecting negative number), but it will not help you, because your problem is elsewhere.

Comment: To verify your problem is elsewhere do the simple test first, change the code to: "`mov ax,-1 cmp ax,0 jl negative nop`" and run it in debugger, you should see the `jl` to jump. Now change the `mov ax,-1` to some positive number, the `jl` should not jump. You can then replace `cmp ax,0` with `test ax,ax` and step over it in debugger again, to see that it works. Also `test ax,0x8000` will work and any other immediate value >= 32768. ... and while you are in debugger, remove the fake `mov ax,test_value`, and see what is your real value and problem.

Comment: @Ped7g Ok. Will try and let you know. Thanks.

Comment: BTW don't even try to add some more comments without trying the debugger first. If you don't know what is debugger, search the http://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info and take few hours/days to learn to use `gdb` or some other.

Comment: When you test `ax`, you are testing a 16-bit value. Are you actually trying to test an 8-bit or 32-bit value? If so, you should use either `al` or `eax`.

Comment: @CodyGray probably 8bit, because 32b would require quite some number to have b15 zero, unlikely to be seen in test data by hand of newcomer. But actually I suspect him to work with ASCII string data... which would make this completely irrelevant either way. :D

Comment: Hey @ped7g can you please show me executing of that instructions (by using online compiler or any other method). because its not working for me.Its not jumping

Comment: [Edit] your question to show the actual code that you are using, *in context*. Include the part where you initialize the `ax` register.

Comment: @CodyGray Just i want to test single digit decimal number like 1,2,-1 etc.

Comment: I promise you that `mov ax, -1` + `cmp ax, 0` + `jl IsNegative` will work. So your code *must* look different than that if it isn't working. We can't tell you why it isn't working unless we can *actually see* it.

Comment: BTW i am using NASM on linux ubuntu.

Comment: Is there any online compiler for this so that i can test the code and will report you,

Comment: THis is my program BTW

Comment: Well, as we expected, there are several major problems everywhere else, not in the `cmp` + `jl`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Online nasm with linux: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_assembly_online.php

Example:

```
section .text
    global _start       ;must be declared for using gcc
_start:                     ;tell linker entry point
    mov     ax,-4     ; test value

doFewTests:
    push    eax

    cmp     ax,0
;    test    ax,ax
;    test    ax,0x8000

    jl      handleNegative
    ; handle non-negative
    ; fake conversion to ASCII for numbers 0-9
    add     al,'0'
    mov     ecx,strPositive
    mov     edx,lenPositive
    mov     [ecx+edx-2],al
    jmp     printMessage
handleNegative:
    ; fake conversion to ASCII for numbers -9 to -1
    neg     al
    add     al,'0'
    mov     ecx,strNegative
    mov     edx,lenNegative
    mov     [ecx+edx-2],al
printMessage:
    mov     ebx, 1      ;file descriptor (stdout)
    mov     eax, 4      ;system call number (sys_write)
    int     0x80        ;call kernel
    pop     eax
    inc     ax
    cmp     ax,5
    jl      doFewTests  ; do -4 to +4 demonstration loop
    ; exit
    mov     eax, 1      ;system call number (sys_exit)
    int     0x80        ;call kernel

section .data

strPositive db 'Positive number: x', 10
lenPositive equ $ - strPositive
strNegative db 'Negative number: -x', 10
lenNegative equ $ - strNegative
```

BTW, there's no point to work without debugger, and you obviously didn't listen. This site is good only for demonstrating final example, it's impossible to learn Assembly programming on it, because it doesn't have debugger installed.

If you don't listen and you just search for the easy way, you will never learn Assembly, because in Assembly there are only "proper" ways, no easy ones.

**LAST TIME**: use the debugger.

If you don't know how, use the instructions at bottom of https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info to get into `gdb`, then find some other tutorial/docs how to use it.

Eventually try some graphics frontend like `ddd` (but last time I tried, the experience was not very good, learning to control `gdb` is long term investment in GNU world, as that debugger is used also by other high level languages, so don't hesitate to spend **DAYS** on it.

(I'm using `edb` debugger, but I had to compile it from sources, so that's probably another "can of worms" for you).

---

Output of that fugly example:

```
sh-4.3$ nasm -f elf *.asm; ld -m elf_i386 -s -o demo *.o
sh-4.3$ demo
Negative number: -4
Negative number: -3
Negative number: -2
Negative number: -1
Positive number: 0
Positive number: 1
Positive number: 2
Positive number: 3
Positive number: 4
```